# Persisting an object across multiple sessions in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the best way of persisting a collection of objects across multiple sessions in ASP.Net MVC?  I'd like to have a collection in which many users can "take the next X" from the collection - e.g. process the next X records that someone else isn't using - so it will have to persist in the service layer across multiple sessions of the the application.

It's an internal website, so there's no worry of users getting to things they're not supposed to, it will only be used by those who should have access to the data.

Considering using a static object in the service layer, but I'm not sure how/whether that will persist across sessions, or am I approaching this entirely the wrong way and should I be using the database to store the information instead?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this definitely seems like a concern for the database - storing this in memory (ala your static variable approach) does not allow load balancing and the information will be lost each time IIS recycles the App Pool.

Comment: This is kind of what I was thinking, I thought I'd throw it out for opinions as there seemed no good ways to do it.

Comment: @IanCotterill A database seems like a reasonable way to me - you can easily abstract away the persistence mechanism in your code (so it could easily be replaced by a web service say). This is the beauty of SO, the benefit of a collective experience in software!

Answer (score 1):

I would rather go the DB way. Always consuming from the same place and avoid having to keep track with multiple lists. You can get the Next X from the DB and flag them and move to the next ones